# Drupal 9: How to add field value on path url?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-9, drupal-path-aliases

Im creating a new multilingual site using drupal 9. Is it possible to add field value(im using taxonomy) from content types after the domain?(eg. [www.example.com/**value**/en/about](http://www.example.com/**value**/en/about)). And also restrict access to pages that do not have that value?

Domain should be the same, just the value will be different and should be visible on the URL.
Any suggestions or alternatives? Thank you.

Comment: You can pass parameters in the Routes, check this [Using parameters in routes](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/parameters-in-routes/using-parameters-in-routes)

Comment: seems to not work